# how to take input in Java from user?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java but quite good at C. I want to take the input from user in Java. Could anyone please suggest the basic concept with the exact code? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried google already, e.g. "java console input"?

Comment: You question is a little broad, but you probably want to create a `Swing`\JavaFX app Or use a command line option using `Scanner`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html

Comment: Thanks. Kenneth I am used to C so Java is a bit confusing. I am trying to get a value for the limit of a loop but for that also I have to write a function. right?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Main {

        public static void main (String [] args)
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String inputText = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }
```

`import java.util.Scanner;`
This imports the java library that will allow you to read data from the specified input source.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Gets a working instance of the Scanner library in `sc` which will go get the input for you from the standard input of the system, `System.in`, in our case, which is the keyboard.

```
String inputText = sc.nextLine();
```

This code asks the `sc` instance to get the line of text typed by the user and set it into the `inputText` variable.

Note that when `sc.nextLine()` is called, it halts any execution and waits for user input and proceeds only when the user presses the *Enter* on the keyboard.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it's substantially more detailed than my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple idea using a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter something searched.. ");
   String input = scan.next();
   System.out.println("your input is " + input);
 }
```